# remove special chars in array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I wanted to loop over an array of string in js and mutate the element which is having special character by removing I am able to do it with string  but not with an array of string

```js
var names = ['created_at', 'placed-at', 'room-no'];
console.log(names)
names.forEach((element) => {
 element = element.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' ');
});
console.log(names)
//however this regex work fine with independent strings like below 
var name= "created_at"
name = name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' ');
console.log(name)
```

Comment: you are probably looking for a `map` rather then a `forEach`

Comment: let me try with map

Comment: Be aware that you should capture the return of the map

Comment: sure, noted on this

Comment: Maybe `names[i] = element.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' ');`? But `map` is better solution.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Berto99. I would be very kind of you if you help me understand why isnt it working with foreach and why did it worked with map 

I had recently muted an array of obj with forEach 

       array.forEach((element) => {
          let date = new Date(element.created_at * 1000);
          element.created_at = moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
        });

and that worked 
so i was runnig my head aroud it that it should also work with forEach

TIA

Comment: Read the answer from [Rajdeep Debnath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67821142/402037)

Comment: oky @Andreas will give it a read

Comment: [Read my complete answer bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821090/remove-special-chars-in-array-of-strings-in-javascript/67821143#67821143)

Answer (score 3):

Array is reference type but the strings inside the array are value type. As you are updating individual string which is value type hence it's not updating original array.
Either you can use `map` function which will return entire new array.
Or foreach with index to mutate the current array.

```
names.map((element) => element.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' '));
```

or

```
names.forEach((element, idx) => {
 names[idx] = element.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The forEach () method is a loop that starts a function for each element.
in your questioon you put an arrow function, but you might as well use a non-arrow function as follows:

```js
names.forEach(myReplaceFunction)
```

following your question this would be equivalent to:

```js
function myReplaceFunction(element) {
 element = element.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' ');
}
```

which as you can see cannot reach any element of your initial array (even if you use the term element)

Luckily the forEach method sends 3 arguments

1. the value of the iterated element (because it is a simple type [have a look there](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/) )
2. his index finger
3. a reference to the array used

You must therefore change the code of this function to:

```js
function myReplaceFunction(element, currentIndex, originArray) {
 originArray[currentIndex] = element.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ' ');
}
```

which simply boils down to

```js
var names = ['created_at', 'pla-ced-at', 'room-no'];
 
names.forEach((el,i,arr) => {
 arr[i] = el.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, ' ');
});

console.log(names)
```

> small note, your regex is wrong, it only allows you to replace the first occurrence found, I changed it to: `/[^a-zA-Z ]/g`

Comment: _"which as you can see cannot reach any element of your initial array"_ - That's only true for primitives, which OP already [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821090/remove-special-chars-in-array-of-strings-in-javascript/67821143?noredirect=1#comment119876459_67821090).

Comment: @Andreas ... it's true, I missed that, but as it requires a longer explanation, I put a good(?) link ...)